# Wrapping Arbitrary XML within XML

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I need to embed arbitrary (syntactically valid) XML documents within a wrapper XML document. The embedded documents are to be regarded as mere text, they do not need to be parseable when parsing the wrapper document.

I know about the "[CDATA trick](http://eai.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/seebeyond-l/xml-within-xml-possible-788127)", but I can't use that if the inner XML document itself contains a CDATA segment, and I need to be able to embed *any* valid XML document. Any advice on accomplishing this--or working around the CDATA limitation--would be appreciated.

Comment: Reading your comment to my response, it seems like we're talking about two different things. I was talking about encapsulating XML text within an XML document: for example, putting an example program into a posting. You seem to be talking about simply wrapping well-formed XML with more well-formed XML. In this case a textual concatenation might be your best bet (although both pieces of text should be produced by a serializer).

Comment: Note that such wrapping will not involve CDATA ...

Comment: The well-formed XML that I need to wrap is itself a well-formed XML document, that then must be embedded within an XML document (and be subsequently extractable). So your answer, plus my epiphany, neatly solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to properly escape the text. You don't say what language you're using, but generally: you build a DOM, create a Text node that contains your "inner" XML, and then serialize that DOM. The serializer will handle escaping for you.

The key point here is **use a serializer** to produce your output. Don't simply write strings, because you're all but guaranteed to produce something that's not well-formed XML.

Comment: Twice I started to comment that while this answer was good, it didn't fit what I was doing, which, way oversimplified, was receiving a text stream that contained an XML document that had to be wrapped within XML and sent back out. Parsing to a DOM wasn't part of the task. But I aborted my comments. This answer just kept weighing on me, and I finally had an epiphany: while input was time critical, output was not. So spin up a thread to buffer the XML, parse it, wrap it, and serialize it. Done!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by simply adding the document (without its <`?xml` declaration) as a child tom some parent. SOAP is doing this - it has a `<Body>` element that can contain whatever xml message one wants to send.

SOAP defines the XSD this way:

```
<xs:element name="Body" type="tns:Body" />
  <xs:complexType name="Body">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" 
          maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="lax">
    </xs:anyAttribute>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you escape the ending angular bracket of the inner CDATA, most XML parsers will not complain about the well-formedness of your XML. Using this "workaround", you should be able to nest multiple CDATA sections.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SomeData>
<![CDATA[
<SomeMoreData>
<![CDATA[
yeah, this trick rocks! ...
]]&gt;
</SomeMoreData>
]]>
</SomeData>
```

Note that the inner CDATA has its ending ">" escaped as `&gt;`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [XInclude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XInclude) instead of trying to embed an XML document inside another. The XInclude parse="text" attribute will force the XML to be treated as text, not markup.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is that you can have adjacent CDATA sections. `<![CDATA[A]]><![CDATA[B]]>` is the same as `<![CDATA[AB]]>`. Hence, you can have `<![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>`, a `]]>` close tag split over two `CDATA` sections.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) are for?