# JAX-WS HowTo get xml string from request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have such issue.
I have web service

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ServerWebService {

@WebMethod
    WSResponse calculateValue(@WebParam(name = "WSRequest") WSRequest request) throws ServerFault, TfmRequestInputFault;
}
```

with POJO for request:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WSRequest implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String promotionData;

    public String getPromotionData() {
        return promotionData;
    }

    public void setPromotionData(String promotionData) {
        this.promotionData = promotionData;
    }
```

}

Xml request is something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cal:calculateValue>
         <WSRequest>
            <promotionData>
                **<anotherXML>....</anotherXML>**
            </promotionData>
         </WSRequest>
      </cal:calculateValue>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When the request come to web service, XML from  is not saved to String field of my POJO. Tell me please what i'm doing wrong?
This issue happens only with xml as field, when simple string comes as  - everything works fine.

Comment: is it possible to include the promotion data content inside the cdata tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: CDATA not allowed in my situation

Comment: hmm..one work around would be trying to replace the '<' & '>' characters with '&lt;' and '&rt;'

Comment: send your xml in attachment or serialized it as in this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777302/wrapping-arbitrary-xml-within-xml